# Fire API Event through DE Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, journeybuilder

So I have an interesting use case here. So I was wondering if there is a way write up an api entry event for a data event that happens within a DE is Marketing Cloud.

I would love to write API entry events with data that is already inside the Marketing Cloud. Instead of the event firing from an event from my database the event fires when a record is updated within a Data Extension. This way I can work within the Marketing Cloud and not mess with our external data structures.

Maybe something like this?

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
"ContactKey": "ID601",
"EventDefinitionKey":"AcmeBank-AccountAccessed",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": {
    "accountNumber":"{{Contacts.Attributes.DataExtension.Field}}",
    "patronName":"{{Contacts.Attributes.DataExtension.Field}}" }
}
```

Comment: what  is your requirement ? you need fire the journey builder  event using Rest Api

Comment: Correct, but I want the event to stem from a data change that happen within marketing cloud. Can I write an entry event for a data change that happens within the marketing cloud only? Like an API call upon itself.

Answer (score 0):

use like this request body

```
{
"ContactKey":"DE external key here",
"EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-event key here",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": {
    "Email":"test@gmail.com",
    "Name":"test"
   }
}
```